# What motivated this sudden surrender during Marvel’s Civil War series?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, marvel-civil-war

I've recently read the  "Civil War" comic series, and feel quite disappointed by its ending.

> In the final battle, just when Captain America is about to beat Iron Man, and although the fight is pretty even is slowly falling by his "team" side, he is tackled by common folks that try to protect Stark. Then he gets totally demoralized, and like an epiphany, he realizes that he was wrong and Tony was right, surrendering and leaving the resistance headless and unable to keep fighting (as the anti-registration team were just following him).

Now, the finale seems too abrupt for me. There is no logical explanation for such a sudden change in the attitude of the main characters involved and although I can understand the main idea why

> the fear and hate that common folk feel for supers is what makes him change his point of view,

it's also stated during the narration that

> he's fighting just to avoid that people accept it as a common way of thinking, making correlation to Nazism and apartheid.

So, are there any parallel comics where more scenes explain this sudden change of mind in a more logical way, or add value to it, showing him, for example, having doubts about what his side are doing?

BONUS:

> Where the hell did the common folk that tackled the Captain appear from? There were several pages of superhero madness destroying everything in the vicinity. With the current state of paranoia why didn't they flee or get evacuated?

Comment: As someone who hasn't seen the movie yet, it's a shame your question had a spoiler in it. :)

Comment: @RobertHorvick literally none of this happens in the movie.It's not even remotely similar.

Comment: That's both good to know and disappointing.

Comment: then is a comic book spoiler. although ill never read them , you could change the title to "Civil War comic Ending explanation".

Comment: Why are people on Stack Exchange so thoughtless towards ther peers as to constantly include spoilers in titles? Unless it's part of pop culture (ex. Luke : Darth Vader), have some respect and consideration for others.

Comment: No spoilers in titles please!!! We see these damned things in the Hot Network Questions. And SE won't give us filters to remove this particularly egregious site full of spoilers from the HNQ.

Comment: @RobertHorvick: if comic book movies followed comic plots, they’d be about seven hours long. Different media suit different methods of storytelling.

Comment: @Almo The new title, while not spoilerific, is also not SFF-specific. I saw this in the HNQ and thought it was on History.SE for a moment. Ah well, at least now we can prepare for the "I saw the title and thought this was about the American Civil War!" comments.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite thanks

Answer (score 19):

**Steve didn't surrender because he realised he was wrong, he surrendered because he realised that the cost of the fight was greater than the cost of giving up.**

We see this in the final panels of the battle - dozens and dozens of superheroes laying injured in the street, buildings damaged, relationships ruined. Steve realises that even if he is right, it's all gone too far (as demonstrated by the civilians having to literally pull him off Tony Stark), which is why he gives in.

Comment: And I believe in his interview with Sally Floyd post-arrest (the infamous "Do you even know what Myspace is?" one), he made it clear he still believes in his side, he just believes he should have come at it more peaceably and maybe taken his argument and objections directly to the people rather than start a fight in the streets.

Comment: @starpilotsix exactly. Which was my big complaint with the story. Tony Stark is the "bad guy" but Steve abandoned his way of thinking right out of the gate and has to be reminded in order to stop the fighting.